# IF statement not detecting numbers

Tags: roblox

My if statement is not working, in other words it's not wanting to detect player scores. I've also tried checking if it exists.

Here is the whole script:

```
local price = script.Parent.Price.Value
local item = script.Parent.Price.Value

local db = true

local function buy(player)
    local itemName = game.ServerStorage.GravityCoil:Clone()
    print("got to click detecting")

    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats").Tix.Value >= 5 then
        print("checked price")
        db = false
        player.leaderstats.Tix.Value = player.leaderstats.Tix.Value - price
        itemName.Parent = player.Backpack
        print("gave item")
        wait(.10)
        db = true
    end
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(buy)
```

But we need to focus on one part,

```
    if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats").Tix.Value >= 5 then
        print("checked price")
        db = false
        player.leaderstats.Tix.Value = player.leaderstats.Tix.Value - price
        itemName.Parent = player.Backpack
        print("gave item")
        wait(.10)
        db = true
```

There are no errors, warnings, anything in the console. I can't pinpoint the problem, I've joined discord servers, I've looked at roblox forums, I just can't find a solution to this problem! So please, if you have 30 minutes just to look at this and try to post an answer, I will praise you. Have a great day.

Comment: Since there are no errors, are there any messages in the output? Is the "got to click detecting" message showing up?

Comment: If you print out Tix.Value, what is it when the code execute?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest removing the FindFirstChild as leaderstats should already exist in player so there is no need to check for it. Also check if your greater sign is correct as you could have meant to put a lesser sign which resulted in the if statement not working.